# Why can't I run `psql` command even though postgresql.service is running?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

[image]

[image]

[image]

error in text form:

```
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
```

also, I'm getting this error in pgadmin while trying to register a new server:
[image]

error in text form:

```
Unable to connect to server: connection failed: :1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections? connection to server at "localhost (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection ref used Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

Since, `sudo systemmctl status postgresql` and `sudo systemmctl status 'postgresql*'` shows active status, I expected pgadmin to run without a hitch.

Comment: Remember to post your code, status- and error-messages as text, not purely as images. People will not retype your images into a search engine to gather more information about the error and help fix your problem.

Comment: "Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?" well you show that it is running, but is it configured to accept on port 5432?

Comment: Are the `local` entries in `pg_hba.conf` configured correctly (including the chosen password encryption method, `md5` or `scram-sha-256` if used)?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin https://imgur.com/a/B19FIXo

Comment: If you are using `peer` authentication and it is available on your system (see [21.9. Peer Authentication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-peer.html)), then it should work -- though you likely need a mapping between the `postgres` user and whatever your install runs as (most use `postgres` or `postgresql` by default)

Comment: psql worked once, then it didn't work:
working: https://imgur.com/xXTTuS2
not working: https://imgur.com/vhbdLsN
@PeteKirkham

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `/etc/postgresql` has 2 folders: '14' and '15'. is this relevant?
result of `apt list 'postgresql*' --installed`:
https://imgur.com/WRtDybX

Comment: Yes -- that is relevant. One is for version 14, the other is for version 15. If you just recently updated to 15, you will need to migrate your postgres data to the new version of the server. You have two options, dump your databases and reload into the new version of the server or using the `pg_upgrade` script (but will require both versions be installed). I've always had more luck dumping and reloading and the `pg_upgrade` script always finds a way to complain about an encoding value (or something else) and quits. Manual dump and restore never fails... Just my $0.02 there.

Comment: The [Archwiki Postgres Page - 7 Upgrading](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PostgreSQL#Upgrading_PostgreSQL) does a good job explaining both. If you did just upgrade, the config under 15 is likely not fully configured.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin i dont have any databases in version 14 (pgadmin doesn't show any). and version 14 isn't actually installed (only the files remain on /etc/postgresql and maybe somewhere else too, should i delete them?)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin how should i configure the missing configs?

Comment: No....... Don't delete until you manually examine both directories (generally `/usr/lib/postgres/14` and `../15`). The `data` directory is usually what holds the config and the initialized data store. Make sure you have a handle on what resides where before you start deleting.

Comment: Follow the link I provided -- it does a good walkthrough on how to initialize and configure your server. (adjust paths, etc. as needed for pop.os.

Comment: Then your database was never correctly initialized. You have to do that before there is a data store and config directory setup for postgres. That's all part of the initialization process.

Comment: how do i remove everything and do a reinstall?
i removed and reinstalled the installed programs from apt once but these files remain which cause issues @DavidC.Rankin

imma follow this: https://kb.objectrocket.com/postgresql/how-to-completely-uninstall-postgresql-757

Comment: You can simply delete (or move) the `data` directory` to anything you like, delete it or (as root) `mv data dataold`. Then just follow the initialization steps in the link. E.g., after `sudo -iu postgres` run `initdb -D /var/lib/postgres/data` (change `/var/lib/postgres` as needed for pop os) I recommend using the defaults rather than specifying the characters set, etc.. -- makes it easier when attempting `pg_upgrade`.

Comment: Thank you @DavidC.Rankin my issue has been solved:
i removed all files and programs and reinstalled them. following this: https://kb.objectrocket.com/postgresql/how-to-completely-uninstall-postgresql-757

Comment: Hey, congrats! It's not hard once you have gone through it once and know where all the pieces are buried. The first time is a bit daunting learning where everything lives and what initialization steps are required. Enjoy. PostgreSQL is a great RDBM. I've got it running on everything from Raspberry Pi's to full blown Quad-quad processor SuperMicro servers. I run both MariaDB and Postgres -- and enjoy them both.

Comment: thank you for ur advice. best wishes to ur endeavours! @DavidC.Rankin

Answer (score 0):

its fixed, i removed all files and programs and reinstalled them. following this:
https://kb.objectrocket.com/postgresql/how-to-completely-uninstall-postgresql-757